# jquery bubble pop up not working

Tags: jquery, bubble-popup

All, 

I am trying to use jquery bubble up v2.3.1. 
But It seem not working on JSFiddle. 
Can anyone tell me why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').attr('placeholder', 'Enter number bwteen 1 and 100');
    $('tr').CreateBubblePopup({ innerHtml: 'This is a Bubble Popup!' });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/sks358zo/10/

Comment: and I tried jquery bubble, which is not working either. Here is another version of JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/sks358zo/12/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sks358zo/13/

```
http://sole.dimi.uniud.it/~giorgio.brajnik/stuff/jqueryBubblePopup/Examples/js/jquery.bubblepopup.v2.3.1.min.js
```

Make sure the scripts you added as external resources actually exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got the external resource from http://www.ymic3dworld.com/lightwindow2/jQueryBubblePopup/Documentation/index.html  I just simply copy and paste the script src and link href into JSFiddle, what is wrong with that? I had a look at your JSFiddle. It works, but the popup bubble has grid, do you know why?

Comment: Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/sks358zo/14/ still not working. I don't know why the external resource is snaeky ~~~